# How can I get readline/rlwrap-like functionality when using clojure.main/repl?

Tags: clojure, readline, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop, rlwrap

How can I get readline-like (or rlwrap-like) functionality from my REPL when I use the [`repl` function from `clojure.main`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.main/repl)?

The background to this is that I'm utilizing and customizing the [`break` function](https://github.com/joyofclojure/book-source/blob/master/first-edition/src/joy/breakpoint.clj#L17) from The Joy of Clojure, First Edition.  I'm using it from inside the `lein repl` REPL.  When my "breakpoint" kicks in, the readline-like functionality of Leiningen's REPL is gone, which is kind of inconvenient.  My muscle memory makes me hit <kbd>↑</kbd> followed quickly by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Before I can stop myself, I've got this in my terminal:

```
debug=> ^[[A
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init13211381000659590518.clj:1:1)
```

And now my REPL is stuck and I have to kill the terminal or the process to get out.  I'd like very much if I could either get readline working in this second-level REPL or at least prevent this common issue from derailing my debug sessions.

Comment: Isn't `rlwrap` helping here?

Comment: rlwrap works in the normal `lein repl` REPL, but not in the REPL within the REPL.

Comment: `lein repl` brings its own readline stuff.  So `rlwrap` is what i am using with non-lein-repl. So i'd _assume_ that rlwrap alone (no-lein-outer-repl, inner-repl) would not care (unless the repl-in-a-repl messes with std(out|in). Yet i don't know how to disable the jreadline2 (?) support in lein.

Answer (score 3):

You should use rebel readline, a new repl for clojure developed by bhauman the same guy who brought is figwheel.

[`https://github.com/bhauman/rebel-readline`](https://github.com/bhauman/rebel-readline)

It has rlwrap features, syntax highlighting and multi line code editing all in the terminal.

Comment: rebel-readline looks great! Can you tell us more about it, like how to make the `break` function from _The Joy of Clojure_ support readline?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the `rlwrap` utility would help there, because the inner REPL is held by the outer one. So the input is being controlled by Java code, not the `rlwrap` tool.

You are causing an exception since you input a wrong value. I remember, the `clojure.main/repl` function might take an additional argument to handle exceptions. Probably, you could handle it somehow and just print a string "wrong input value" instead. Take a look at [the documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.main/repl) for REPL.

Also, you may implement your own REPL for debugging. Long ago, I used to write some kind of it, here what I've got:

```
(defn repl []
  (let [input (read)]
    (if (= input 'q)
      nil
      (do
        (try
          (let [result (eval input)]
            (println result))
          (catch Exception e
            (println e)))
        (recur)))))
```

That function just prompts for a proper Clojure expression in an endless loop, evaluates it and prints the result. In case of a wrong input, it prints the error and carries on. To leave the REPL, input `q`.

Example:

```
(repl)
(+ 1 2) ;; 2
fsdf8 9_fsd ;; prints a stack trace
q ;; returns nil and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Emacs with [Cider](https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as your repl. When you `(break)` you'll be bumped out of the Cider repl and into the Emacs Minibuffer, where your standard emacs editing shortcuts (upon which readline is modeled) continue to apply.